# Shortcut keys of Clover do not work,why?

Tags: windows-7, tabbed-browsing

I installed [`Clover`](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/System-Tweak/Clover-EJIE.shtml) on Win7.But it's shortcut keys(for example Ctrl+T,Ctrl+W,...) does not work.

I re-installed it, then search in Google. Only thing that may be correspond is ExplorerWatcher class that adds on to IE. But it is enable.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried?

Comment: @CharlieRB First I re installed it,then search in Google.Only thing that may be correspond is `ExplorerWatcher class` that adds on to IE.But it is enable.

Comment: Sometimes the keys stop working because the window has lost keyboard focus. Simply clicking the window should fix that. If other keys are working and/or clicking the window/tab-bar doesn’t fix it, then it may be a bug. See if the [latest version](http://ejie.me/#tabber12_a_1) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I began using Clover in Windows XP this past weekend and had no problems with it, but when I tried it in Windows 7, I experienced the hotkey problems you mentioned.

The problems I had were because I had extracted it from the installer and was running just the program. This was fine in Windows XP, but in Windows 7 with its different architecture and increased security and access restrictions, some of the hotkeys didn’t work correctly. I fixed it by registering Clover’s `.dll` and now all the hotkeys work as expected. Yay!

You can fix that by re-installing, making sure to run the installer as admin. Alternately, you can register just the extension:

1. Open the *Start* menu
2. Type `cmd`
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>
4. Use the `cd` command to navigate to the clover folder (defaults to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Clover`)
5. Register it with the following command: `regsvr32 TabHelper64.dll` (on a 32-bit system, use `regsvr32 TabHelper32.dll`)

Comment: What do I do if I don't have admin rights and am using the portable version? (http://sourceforge.net/projects/newkelp/files/Clover%20Portable/)